# Change textbox focus using enter keys

Tags: vb.net

Is there a more simple way to do this?

i have 21 textbox 3 rows what i want is when i press enter in any of the textbox in row1 the focus would jump in the next row. its easy because i only have 3 rows but if i add more rows
i have to code the keydown event again.

```
Private Sub TextBox7_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox7.KeyDown, TextBox6.KeyDown, TextBox5.KeyDown, TextBox4.KeyDown, TextBox3.KeyDown, TextBox2.KeyDown, TextBox1.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            TextBox14.Focus()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox8_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox9.KeyDown, TextBox8.KeyDown, TextBox14.KeyDown, TextBox13.KeyDown, TextBox12.KeyDown, TextBox11.KeyDown, TextBox10.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            TextBox21.Focus()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox15_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox21.KeyDown, TextBox20.KeyDown, TextBox19.KeyDown, TextBox18.KeyDown, TextBox17.KeyDown, TextBox16.KeyDown, TextBox15.KeyDown

    End Sub
```

Comment: Ummm... ever hear of Data grid view controls?  While not a directly related to the question, makes rows of text boxes a lot easier to manage

Comment: thats plain textbox though not datagridview textbox.

Comment: I think the suggestion was that you should be using a `DataGridView` rather than individual `TextBoxes`. If you don't want to do that then you should put your `TextBoxes` in a `TableLayoutPanel`. You can then use a single event handler and use the column and row index of the current `TextBox` to determine which `TextBox` to focus based on its column and row index. BTW, you should be calling `Select`, not `Focus`.

Comment: I'm not sure whether the specified duplicate actually addresses the specific requirements in this case. You'd have to ensure that the Tab order was set from top to bottom and then left to right for those `TextBoxes`, but you haven't actually specified what you want to do from a `TextBox` in the bottom row. If you want to wrap back to the first row in the same column then `SelectNextControl` won't work, but if you want to go to the first row and the next column then it will. There's also the matter of what to do from the last control if there are other controls on the form.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be a solution, but I think 1 row
1 How about creating a row event after inserting a textbox into the panel?
example code below

```
Private Sub Toy1Form_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

      For Each txtbox As TextBox In Row1Panel.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)
         AddHandler txtbox.KeyDown, AddressOf Row1Focus
      Next

      For Each txtbox As TextBox In Row2Panel.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)
         AddHandler txtbox.KeyDown, AddressOf Row2Focus
      Next

 End Sub

   Sub Row1Focus(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
      If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
         TextBox14.Focus()
      End If
   End Sub

   Sub Row2Focus(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
      If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
         TextBox15.Focus()
      End If
   End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using a `TableLayoutPanel`:

```vb
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For Each textBox As Control In TableLayoutPanel1.Controls
        AddHandler textBox.KeyDown, AddressOf TextBoxes_KeyDown
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub TextBoxes_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        Dim currentTextBox = DirectCast(sender, Control)
        Dim position = TableLayoutPanel1.GetPositionFromControl(currentTextBox)
        Dim columnIndex = position.Column
        Dim rowIndex = position.Row

        rowIndex += 1

        If rowIndex = TableLayoutPanel1.RowCount Then
            rowIndex = 0
        End If

        Dim newTextBox = TableLayoutPanel1.GetControlFromPosition(columnIndex, rowIndex)

        newTextBox.Select()
    End If
End Sub
```

This assumes that all cells in the table are populated. If there are some empty cells then you would have to allow for that. This code will work for a table of any dimensions.